# Math font for sets?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, amsmath

There is a somewhat conservative script font that's used for sets, contours, and for some different purposes in number theory. I'm sorry I can't describe it better; here are some examples:
[image]
[image]

I'm talking about the `P` that appears as `p\in P` in the first image, and the `C` that appears in the contour integral in the second image.  Any idea how to get this font in LaTeX?

Comment: `\mathcal{P}` and `\mathcal{C}`

Comment: @egreg Yep -- I just got it. I found the answer in the "User's Guide for the amsmath Package" by searching for `mathbb` and looking at its friends.

Comment: @hpesoj626 -- it seems not to be obvious that a letter in a "math alphabet" should be considered a symbol.  i've left a comment on the cited question suggesting a possible extension of the title to cover that situation.

Comment: OK -- now that [that question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-alphabet) has been changed to include this situation, mine is indeed a duplicate. (Not my fault!)

Answer (score 4):

As answered by egreg in the comments, the font is provided by `\mathcal`. I found the answer in the "User's Guide for the amsmath Package" by searching for `mathbb` and looking at the other commands that came up with it.

As commented by Barbara, this kind of question, identifying an alphabet, can be handled in the same way as the question: [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol) That question has now been modified to also cover this case (... "or identify a math alphabet").